# Automated UAT/functional tests on Swing applications without source code

Tags: java, swing, automated-tests, testing

Our team is now working on a big Swing application. Our job basically focuses on writing extensions to the existing framework. A typical job would be adding a new panel/ or adding a new tab with some extra functionalities that suit our need.

It seems FEST can help a lot in terms of unit-test our code. I am going to try it out this week. But the question here is if there is a way to do automated functional testing on the whole application. In another word, we do not only need to test our code but also the framework. After all, UAT is the most important part.

I am currently considering decompiling the jar files we got into source code then we can identify the components and then use FEST.

So, before I get started to give this approach a shot, I think I just ask for ideas and inspirations here. There must be people who have done similar things before. Would be nice if I could learn from the veterans who fought against this before .

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

In my view, Functional tests and unit tests are not well serviced by the same framework. For functional testing, I would recommend you look at [QFTest](http://www.qfs.de/), which understands Swing components, so you get a more stable test than a traditional click-and-keyboard playback mechanism, while still being at the functional level.

Comment: Thank you very much for the link. QFTest looks very interesting. A shame its not free/open source.

Comment: @jas, yes it is unfortunate. I find that the functional testing area isn't well serviced in Open Source. As with most open source tools, they are by developers for developers, which doesn't give you the same kind of automation abilities you need to work with a QA department. Here is a list of open source options, which may or may not meet your needs: http://www.opensourcetesting.org/functional.php

Answer (score 1):

You could consider [ReTest](http://retest.org/en), which is a functional Swing test tool that comes with an interesting approach to regression testing and is packed with AI-based monkey testing.

It is going to be partly open source as well.

Disclaimer: I am the founder of the company creating ReTest.